# Clustering matrix distance between 3 time series

Tags: cluster-analysis, distance, k-means

I have a question about the application of clustering techniques more concretely the K-means.
I have a data frame with 3 sensors (A,B,C):

```
  time      A  |   B   |  C   |
 8:00:00    6     10      11
 8:30:00    11    17      20
 9:00:00    22    22      15
 9:30:00    20    22      21
10:00:00    17    26      26
10:30:00    16    45      29
11:00:00    19    43      22
11:30:00    20    32      22
   ...      ...  ...     ...
```

And I want to group sensors that have the same behavior.

My question is: Looking at the dataframe above, I must calculate the correlation of each object of the data frame and then apply the Euclidean distance on this correlation matrix, thus obtaining a 3 * 3 matrix with the value of distances?

Or do I transpose my data frame and then compute the dist () matrix with Euclidean metric only and then I will have a 3 * 3 matrix with the distances value.

Answer (score 0):

You have just three sensors. That means, you'll need *three* values, d(A B), d(B,C) and d(A B). Any "clustering" here does not seem to make sense to me? Certainly not k-means. K-means is for points (!) In R^d for small d.

Choose any form of time series similarity that you like. Could be simply correlation, but also DTW and the like.

Answer (score 0):

Q1: No. Why: The correlation is not needed here.

Q2: No. Why: I'd calculate the distances differently

For the first row, R' built-in s `dist()` function (which uses Euclidean distance by default)

`dist(c(6, 10, 11))`

gives you the intervals between each value

```
   1 2
------
2| 4  
3| 5 1
```

item 2 and 3 are closest to each other. That's simple.

But there is no single way to calculate the distance between a point and a group of points. There you need a linkage function (min/max/average/...)

What I would do using R's built-in `kmeans()` function:

- Ignore the date column,
- (assuming there are no NA values in any A,B,C columns)
- scale the data if necessary (here they all seem to have same order of magnitude)
- perform KMeans analysis on the A,B,C columns, with k = 1...n ; evaluate results
- perform a final KMeans with your suitable choice of k
- get the cluster assignments for each row
- put them in a new column to the right of C